# javax.mail from is not set

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send email using JNDI, but for some strange reason the from field is not set.

context.xml:

```
 <Resource name="email/user" 
    description="support email"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
    username="user@server.net"
    password="pass"
    mail.debug="false"
    mail.user="user@server.net"
    mail.from="user@server.net"
    mail.transport.protocol="smtp" 
    mail.host="mail.server.net"
    mail.smtp.host="mail.server.net"
    mail.smtp.auth="true"
    mail.smtp.from="user@server.net"
    mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
    mail.smtp.submitter="user@server.net"/>
```

And how I'm getting this to application:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Session userEmail = (Session) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/email/user");
```

And everything is fine, but when I'm sending this email to some servers I receive return message:
 **We can't accept your message - missing From: (#5.3.0)**

*Additional question:*

How to set nice looking from?
I tried this:

```
mail.from="company XYZ &lt;user@server.net&gt;"
```

But it doesn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason. The issue was in the message creation.

I was missing the **messsage.setFrom();**

Code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setFrom(); //this was missing
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=" + charset); 
//... set recipients, ....
Transport.send(message);
```

Now my both questions are answered. The "nice looking from" is also working now.